# jquery .get not getting

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Not sure what I'm missing? trying to get html from remote domain (I know about cross domain ext...) but this as worked in the past...

Can't see where I'm going wrong:

CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
    <link href="http://jqmdesigner.appspot.com/gk/lib/jquery.mobile/1.4.2/flatui/jquery.mobile.flatui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js">     </script>
    <title>get the html from a website</title>
    <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {            
$.get("https://www.miemssalert.com/chats/Default.aspx?hdRegion=5",  function(data) {
            $(".ui-content").html( data );
            alert( "Load was performed." );
        })
            .done(function() {
                alert( "second success" );
            })
            .fail(function() {
                alert( "error" );
            })
            .always(function() {
                alert( "finished" );
            });
});
    </script>
</head>    
<body>          
<!-- Page: home  -->
    <div id="home" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
        <h3>GET WEB DATA</h3>
        </div>
        <div role="main" class="ui-content"> 
        </div>
    </div>           
</body>
```

Comment: So what is wrong? Do you get an error? Or is the result empty? Or what?

Comment: do you get any of the alerts?

Comment: yes - the .fail and .always

Comment: yes - but this has always returned html from Safari browser.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain check this may help

Comment: @BarclayVision ALWAYS include relevant errors inside the question. it shouldn't take 43 minutes for us to figure out that this is simply a CORS setup problem when you have a blatantly obvious error in your console telling you that it is one.

Comment: @Kevin B I understand your frustration with the error on a different browser, I didn't test on Firefox until after I had posted and replied to your first post, but thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the document ready:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $.get( .....

});
```

Since the `ui-content` div isn't loaded yet there is no place to display the data.

Comment: I have updated question, yea, I have that as well, still .fails!

Comment: While not having this can cause a race condition, not having it won't impact the success/failure of the ajax request.

Comment: Hmm, do you get any console errors?

Comment: no - no error, just the .get .fail

Comment: my alerts are firing on .fail and .always

Comment: Your ajax returns an error, can it be due to the good old Same origin Policy? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 0):

The URL in `$.get` seems to be unavailable. Just open it in a browser and see that it does not give you a result (or answer at all). That's probably why the code has been working before.

Comment: The URL https://www.miemssalert.com/chats/Default.aspx?hdRegion=5 is working fine.

Comment: Now it is. It wasn't before, for me atleast. Hopefully the code is working now.

Comment: no not working and URL has been tested several times...

Comment: I do see a cross domain error in firebug on firefox browser, but like I said, I have used the same code in mobile phone gap projects to get remote html with no problem... Safari Browser has always worked.

Comment: @BarclayVision the fact that it works in another browser doesn't change the fact that you have a cross-domain error. Most likely your CORS setup is incorrect.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "my" CORS setup? wouldn't that be on the remote server that I don't have access too?

Comment: Yes, it would be on the remote server. So, "their" instead of "your" I guess. Can you open the network tab and post the response headers in your question?

Comment: Actually, don't bother, i just tested it from a VM and confirmed the problem. The remote server is not returning CORS headers. You will not be able to retrieve the data with client-side javascript alone from that url.